# libtorrent-rasterbar.so - file very large (60mb+)

Tags: android, c++, c, boost, libtorrent-rasterbar

I've compiled Libtorrent-rasterbar for Android (arm) using the libtorrent-rasterbar sources (github) but ran into some questionable results. Below i list the steps that i took before compilation:

After setting up a stand-alone toolchain for arm i moved the openssl libs into the toolchains lib folder and the headers into the toolchains include folder etc. I did this with the boost-android libs as well. 
Next i exported my environment variables as follows:

```
    export SYSROOT=$ANDROIDNDK/platforms/android-16/arch-arm
    export PATH=/opt/android/toolchains/gcc-arm/bin:$PATH
    export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
    export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
    export CROSSHOST=arm-linux-androideabi
    export CROSSHOME=/opt/android/toolchains/gcc-arm
```

And finally, i configured using the following:

```
./configure --host=$CROSSHOST --prefix=$CROSSHOME --with-boost=$CROSSHOME --with-boost-libdir=$CROSSHOME/lib --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-debug=yes --enable-loggin-yes --with-openssl=$CROSSHOME
```

Everything compiles fine but the shared library produced is way larger than it should be. 65mb. I tried changing my CPPFLAGS to include -O2 (optimization setting) but it didn't make a size difference. Is there anybody who has compiled libtorrent-rasterbar as a shared or static library for android? If so, what was the size of your final binary and what steps did you take?

Thanks so much!

UPDATE: I forgot to include what machine i'm compiling on. Here goes:

1. CPU i7 4770k
2. MEM 16gb 2133mhz
3. HDD 400gb SSD partition
4. OS OSX Yosemite
5. GCC arm-linux-android-gcc (4.9)
6. NDK r10e
7. TOOLCHAIN arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
8. GPU nvidia gtx970 (irrelevant)..

yes, it's a hackintosh.

Comment: "it wouldn't compile using those flags" What were the errors?

Comment: Shared libs tend to be quite big since they compile in ALL the symbols available.  Compile it as a static and link statically.  The linker can then automatically strip out all the unused symbols.

Comment: Or export only public symbols. This is a bit more involved, but it works

Comment: I'll try compiling it as static right now. Will post the results in a few minutes once it finishes. Thanks for the suggestions guys!

Comment: Compiled as a static library, the size is 118.1mb. Ouch! @rost0031

Comment: @TavianBarnes It wouldn't configure when i used the -02 flag. The configure error was "Cannot compile C executable" . It could be my setup but it compiles fine without that flag.

Comment: Try linking against it with `-Wl,--gc-sections` flag to gcc.  That should strip out all the unused symbols.

Comment: @Seth Then the relevant error will be in `config.log`

Comment: @rost0031 So, change the LDFLAGS to include -Wl and --gc-selections? Thanks!

Comment: If the linker is being called by directly calling `ld`, then you don't need the `-Wl,`.  If it's calling gcc, it has to know to pass the flag to the linker, hence the `-Wl,--gc-sections`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Checking the log now. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @rost0031 I'll try compiling it with the -verbose flag so i know for sure how the linking process takes place.

Comment: @TavianBarnes the error is "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-02'"

Comment: @TavianBarnes should i set the optimization for both the CFLAGS and the CPPFLAGS?

Comment: @Seth Just CFLAGS is fine (for Android) because the NDK includes them when building C++ files too.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Thanks. I just re-compiled with the -O2 flag got the same results. One massive 118.1mb .a file.

Comment: Using clang i got the size down to 51mb... still way to big for usage.

Comment: @TavianBarnes - Success (presumably) . I ran "arm-linux-androideabi-strip" on the .a and .so files. This brought the .a size from 91mb to 5.5mb. I'm presuming that they will work but i haven't tried yet. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: @Seth You can also add `-s` to `LDFLAGS` to do the same thing :)

Comment: @Seth Also `--enable-debug=yes` might help

Comment: @TavianBarnes Thanks. I'll try re-compiling with those flags. You all have been very helpful!

Comment: @Seth You're welcome!  And of course I meant `--enable-debug=no` :P